# Accessing sensors from Service

Tags: android, service, sensors

Is there a way to access sensors from android `Service`? for example `Accelerometer`? if yes, could someone point to good tutorial on doing that? Because there doesn't seem to be any tutorial on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access sensor data with [getSystemService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService%28java.lang.String%29) anywhere you have a valid Context. So the tutorials for reading accelerometer data in an Activity can be easily applied for reading accelerometer data in a Service, you don't need a special tutorial for this.

```
 private final SensorManager mSensorManager;
 private final Sensor mAccelerometer;
 ...

 public void accessAccelerometer() {
     mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
     mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
 }
```

Comment: how about registering listener? can it be done from service?

Comment: [registerListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener%28android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int%29) is a member of SensorManager, since we can create a SensorManager in a Service we can also call its methods. So, yes.